# Scheduled task : Error 0X3 but Log doesn't give any error

Tags: scheduled-tasks, robocopy

I have several tasks using `Robocopy.exe`, On One of those tasks, I get a error result `0X3` but the log file doesn't display any error.
Here is the command :

```
ROBOCOPY \\X\L$\FORMATION \\Y\O$\FORMATION /MIR /sec /W:2 /R:5 /log:c:\O_journal.log
```

I tried to launch it without the task scheduler, it worked fine without ant errors.

I know that the error `0X3` is : `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`.But the log file doesn't display any error.

If someone have any clue or any methods...

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a script running on a Windows Server 2012R2 domain controller. It may have something to do with the user account that is used to launch the scheduled process is not in the local administrator's group. The local Administrator group works a little differently on a domain controller. I'm not a server admin so am not able to explain why this matters. I've assumed the fact that my user account is not in the local administrator group that is causing my issue as the Robocopy seems to complete successfully.

Answer (score 6):

This is a standard behavior and relates to exit codes from Robocopy:

```
 0×00   0       No errors occurred, and no copying was done.
                The source and destination directory trees are completely synchronized. 

 0×01   1       One or more files were copied successfully (that is, new files have arrived).

 0×02   2       Some Extra files or directories were detected. No files were copied
                Examine the output log for details. 

 0×04   4       Some Mismatched files or directories were detected.
                Examine the output log. Housekeeping might be required.

 0×08   8       Some files or directories could not be copied
                (copy errors occurred and the retry limit was exceeded).
                Check these errors further.

 0×10  16       Serious error. Robocopy did not copy any files.
                Either a usage error or an error due to insufficient access privileges
                on the source or destination directories.
```

And a combination of them, ie: **0x03 = 0x02 + 0x01**

See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2008/06/16/robocopy-exit-codes/ for a complete explanation.

Comment: `0x01 One or more files were copied successfully` seems to contradict `0x02 ... No files were copied` but, there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue to the path configured on the robocopy script. I have fixed this issue by adding the root directory or the main drive to both source and destination.

*Note: Please make sure that you are an administrator to both Servers (source and destination)*

Example:

> Source: "\\192.168.1.2\e$\my files"
>
> Destination: "\\192.168.1.5\d$\backup"

The root directory or the main drive that I have referred is the "e$" and "d$" as shown above. If this will not included in your script, you will be encountering the "0X3" error in the Scheduler and the scheduler will not works.

*Note: This script is to synchronize/replicate the file from the source to destination.*

Parameters used. `/MIR /E /Z /R:5 /W:5`

This is how the script looks as a whole:

```
robocopy "\\\192.168.1.2\e$\my files" "\\\192.168.1.5\d$\backup" /MIR /E /Z /R:5 /W:5
```

Hope this might help.

Thanks.

Xian